# How can i Show user images on marker?

Tags: android

[image: screenshot of marker set on google map]
Please help me how to set marker on google map as given in image(i.e) in the given shape.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Marker#setIcon(BitmapDescriptor)`

Comment: and use NinePatchDrawable to get a Bitmap of your shape

Comment: I have solved it by using below link ..         
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23966272/android-mask-bitmap-on-canvas-gen-a-black-space

Comment: i have solved this problem using below link    
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23966272/android-mask-bitmap-on-canvas-gen-a-black-space

Answer (score 0):

This way you can set image.

```
BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.proiflepic)


            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
                     .title("Current Location")
                     .snippet("Thinking of finding some thing...")
                     .icon(icon);

            mMarker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

Comment: thank you for reply but i have to make that given shape using bitmap

Comment: @NeeruJain so make a Bitmap of that shape

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623115/google-maps-api-v2-android-add-shape-drawable-as-marker

Comment: @JigneshJain it is showing image in square shape not as above shape

Comment: this is only possible to set it from drawable.

Comment: and if you want that shape with an arrow below, you can use NinePatchDrawable

Comment: I have solved this issue using below link       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23966272/android-mask-bitmap-on-canvas-gen-a-black-space

Answer (score 0):

```
        MarkerOptions userlocmarker = new MarkerOptions();
        userlocmarker.position(new LatLng(userlatitude, userlongitude));
        userlocmarker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.usermarker));
        userlocmarker.title(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.here));
        userlocmarker.snippet("");
        map.addMarker(userlocmarker);
```

Here R.drawable.usermarker is your image..